# Strip dash and any text after from dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown that gets it data from a proprietary system, and we can't change the way it produces values in the dropdown (I know...ridiculous), so I want to use a little jquery and/or javascript to make it neater looking.

For starters, the text in each option is repeated. It should only show a name and a key, but it shows the name and key twice separated by a dash, and the second occurrence appears in brackets, something like this:

```
<select id="productKey">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please make a selection</option>
    <option value="Text 1 | Key 1">Text 1 | Key 1 - (Text 1 | Key 1)</option>
    <option value="Text 2 | Key 2">Text 2 | Key 2 - (Text 2 | Key 2)</option>
    <option value="Text 3 | Key 3">Text 3 | Key 3 - (Text 3 | Key 3)</option>
    <option value="Text 4 | Key 4">Text 4 | Key 4 - (Text 4 | Key 4)</option>
    <option value="Text 5 | Key 5">Text 5 | Key 5 - (Text 5 | Key 5)</option>
    <option value="Text 6 | Key 6">Text 6 | Key 6 - (Text 6 | Key 6)</option>
    <option value="Text 7 | Key 7">Text 7 | Key 7 - (Text 7 | Key 7)</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to strip the options at a - so the list would instead look like this:

```
<select id="productKey">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please make a selection</option>
    <option value="Text 1 | Key 1">Text 1 | Key 1</option>
    <option value="Text 2 | Key 2">Text 2 | Key 2</option>
    <option value="Text 3 | Key 3">Text 3 | Key 3</option>
    <option value="Text 4 | Key 4">Text 4 | Key 4</option>
    <option value="Text 5 | Key 5">Text 5 | Key 5</option>
    <option value="Text 6 | Key 6">Text 6 | Key 6</option>
    <option value="Text 7 | Key 7">Text 7 | Key 7</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

```
var my_options = $("#productKey option");
    my_options.split("-");
$("#productKey").empty().append(my_options);
```

But getting error that `my_options.split is not a function`. I'm guessing because it's an array so I need to loop through the options, but now sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to jQuery's `text()` method, and it will be called for each matching element.

Grab the current text, remove everything after the dash, and return it.

```js
$('#productKey option').text(
  function() {
    // also removes any whitespace before the -
    return this.text.replace(/\s*-.*/, '');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="productKey">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please make a selection</option>
  <option value="Text 1 | Key 1">Text 1 | Key 1 - (Text 1 | Key 1)</option>
  <option value="Text 2 | Key 2">Text 2 | Key 2 - (Text 2 | Key 2)</option>
  <option value="Text 3 | Key 3">Text 3 | Key 3 - (Text 3 | Key 3)</option>
  <option value="Text 4 | Key 4">Text 4 | Key 4 - (Text 4 | Key 4)</option>
  <option value="Text 5 | Key 5">Text 5 | Key 5 - (Text 5 | Key 5)</option>
  <option value="Text 6 | Key 6">Text 6 | Key 6 - (Text 6 | Key 6)</option>
  <option value="Text 7 | Key 7">Text 7 | Key 7 - (Text 7 | Key 7)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware you could pass a function into the setter so that you could act differently based on each item on the collection

Comment: It's not obvious, but it's handy.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the options changing the `text` property of the option. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement

```js
$('select option').each(function(){
   this.text = this.text.split('-')[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="productKey">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please make a selection</option>
    <option value="Text 1 | Key 1">Text 1 | Key 1 - (Text 1 | Key 1)</option>
    <option value="Text 2 | Key 2">Text 2 | Key 2 - (Text 2 | Key 2)</option>
    <option value="Text 3 | Key 3">Text 3 | Key 3 - (Text 3 | Key 3)</option>
    <option value="Text 4 | Key 4">Text 4 | Key 4 - (Text 4 | Key 4)</option>
    <option value="Text 5 | Key 5">Text 5 | Key 5 - (Text 5 | Key 5)</option>
    <option value="Text 6 | Key 6">Text 6 | Key 6 - (Text 6 | Key 6)</option>
    <option value="Text 7 | Key 7">Text 7 | Key 7 - (Text 7 | Key 7)</option>
</select>
```